# sequential count in between 0000-9999

Tags: java

I want to get the count in 4 digits i.e.0 as 0000,1 as 0001,2 as 0002 till 9999.

I am trying the below code but its not working . if anyone can help it will be nice.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String str = ae.getActionCommand();
    if (str.equals("GENERATE PART NO. :")) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/d03", "root", "");
            st = con.createStatement();

            String s = "select value from part where mix='" + jc.getSelectedItem() + "'";

            rs = st.executeQuery(s);
            t1.getText();
            if (rs.next()) {

                String add1 = rs.getString("value");
                t1.setEditable(false);

                String str9 = "EP" + add1;

                for (j = 0; j <= 9999; j++) {

                    String.format("%04d", j);
                    String str10 = str9 + j;
                    String query = "select MC from final";
                    ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery(query);
                    while (rs1.next()) {
                        while (str10.equals(rs1.getString("MC"))) {
                            j++;

                            str10 = str9 + j;
                        }
                        t1.setText(str10);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Be more specific than "it's not working". Include sample output and how it differs from what you want.

Comment: Define "not working"?  What's it doing?

Comment: Here => for (int j = 0; j <= 9999; j++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%04d", j));
        } // will give output from "0000" to "9999"

Comment: You are not using the result of `String.format("%04d", j);` You probably mean `String str10 = str9 + String.format("%04d", j)`

Comment: You're calling String.format, but the way you're using it it needs to be bound to a variable e.g. String tmp = String.format("%04d",j);

Answer (score 4):

`String.format("%04d", j);` does what you want, but you need to use the result of the `format()` method. Currently you are simply discarding the return value.

```
...
for (int j = 0; j <= 9999; j++) {
    String str = String.format("%04d", j);
    System.err.println(str);
}
...
```

Output:

```
0000
0001
0002
0003
...
```

Comment: after generating the value I have to display it in textfield

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is rather this:

```
for (;str10.equals(rs1.getString("MC"));j++) {
    str10 = String.format("%s%04d", str9, j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the following lines:

```
for (j = 0; j <= 9999; j++) {
    String.format("%04d", j);
    String str10 = str9 + j;
```

- The first line moves the `int` `j` from `0` to `9999`.
- The second line takes `j`, formats it as a four-digit string... and then throws the result away.
- The third line adds the `int` `j` to `str9` and gives it to `str10`.

Because you do not save away the result of the `String.format()`, you don't get what you want.

You need to instead do:

```
String str10 = str9 + String.format("%04d", j);
```

This adds the formatted `String` to `str9` and gives it to `str10`

---

And further down, you're duplicating the wrong code:

```
j++;
str10 = str9 + j;
```

You need to rearrange what you are doing: is your `query` string correct? Should there be a `WHERE` or something? What dictates what order data comes from the query? You have a number of questions to ask yourself that we can't help you with.

Comment: Still not able to get the output.....when i try to display the count in JTextField it starts the count from the last value i.e.9999 and so on

Comment: Take a quick look at my edit. I think you are about at the end of your question